# TypeError: Cannot find function getElementById in object

Tags: java, javascript, javax.script

I am doing automation scripting and I need to read data from an iframe (to validate the content). In my java code

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
try
{
  scriptEngine.eval(new FileReader("readIFrameContent.js"));
}
catch (ScriptException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and readIFrameContent.js is

```js
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{
    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    alert('content: ' + content);
}
```

But I get an error.

> javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError:  ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (#3) in  at line number 3

So I googled for a solution and edited the function

```js
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{
    var document = new Object();
    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    alert('content: ' + content);
}
```

and now the error is

> javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError:
>   Cannot find function getElementById in object [object Object]. (#4) in  at line number 4

Suggestions please.

Comment: You don't have any document or window because you probably don't run this via a web browser - right?

Comment: Actually am working on selenium. It does use a web browser but with only a few features enabled. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: No sorry.. one thing is for sure, you can't just create a document out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the statement **var document = new Object();**
Your code should work without this statement.

Comment: No it doesn't. As I explained earlier, without var document = new Object();, it gives the error "javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (#3) in at line number 3"